# creating URL for member profile using API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

The MailChimp GUI uses the following URL format for displaying a member's profile (you must be logged in as the list admin):

> https://us2.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/members/view?id=nnnnnnnnn

I'd like to construct the URL programmatically.

I can retrieve the member's data using the API (GET /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}
), but none of the returned parameters seems to related to the id required for the URL (nnnnnnnnn). The candidates would be "id" and "unique_email_id", but neither one has the right value.

I see that the [subscriber list API](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#read-get_lists_list_id) has a parameter called "web_id". Perhaps the equivalent parameter is just missing from the member response, and there's no way around it?

The closest I'm able to get to this goal is to display the web page intended for the subscriber to update their preferences. (e.g., https://xxx.us2.list-manage.com/profile?u=xxx&id=xxx&e=xxx). In this URL, the member's ID is the one returned by the API.

Comment: I have hit this same problem today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I see the [API](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/lists/list-members/#get_/lists/-list_id-/members/-subscriber_hash-) now has the web_id parameter in the response. I tried it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The [API](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/lists/list-members/#get_/lists/-list_id-/members/-subscriber_hash-) now has the web_id parameter in the response. I tried it and it works!